# React-Leaflet: Scale markers after zooming

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to achieve having markers on a CRS map (specifically a circular avatar with initials) that scale with the map's zoom (they would appear larger or smaller depending on the zoom, not remain the same size), and have been having considerable difficulty achieving performance.

I've tried two different components for the avatars, (still not sure which is right solution):

- [Circle](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components.html#circle) component with a simple, permanent tooltip inside (this component is convenient because it automatically scales).
- [Marker](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components.html#marker) with a `divIcon` passed to it, that I styled to a circle using a border-radius. This one I have to adjust `iconSize` with each zoom level, which brings me to my next issue:

The sticker problem is how get the context of the current zoom state:

- Using the `Map` `onzoomanim:` event on the map to grab the zoom and pass it to the avatars

  - This results in considerable lag between the times each layer renders (e.g. tile, overlay, tooltip) — and is a bad UX
- Use `withLeaflet` HOC to grab the Leaflet context.

  - Though the zoom is deeply nested in the `leaflet` prop, the component is not updating on a zoom change.

Is there something else is Leaflet/React Leaflet that I'm missing that can achieve the desired result?

Comment: Hmm. You could try using a div icon and classes to change the size of stuff.
https://codepen.io/jbccollins/pen/RdBbEY?editors=0110. That example relies on SCSS generation of classes but you could manually write them all out.

Comment: @jbccollins, thanks for the demo. Couldn't quite get your suggestion to work, but here is a fork of what I'm aiming for: https://codepen.io/ianjanicki/pen/drqmKq?editors=0110 (apologies for the poor scss — not terribly familiar with it, hence the specific classNames).  When you zoom in, you can see that that the Tooltip doesn't have a smooth transition like the circle does — it jumps in size as it reacts to the new zoom — which isn't a great UX. In my project, I conditionally render the text during zoom, so it disappears momentarily. This also isn't ideal, but haven't found a better solution.

Comment: @IanJanicki, how did you solve this problem eventually?

Comment: @ralien I ended up using React Leaflet's ImageOverlay component, and fed it an SVG composed of a dataurl leveraging this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-to-dataurl
This allowed me to feed custom parameters to the image