# react-leaflet v3 zoom listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to subscribe on zoom change event, but can't get updates on each zoom change.

My goal is to reach markers scaling on zoom levels. Something like in this case [React-Leaflet: Scale markers after zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55203246/react-leaflet-scale-markers-after-zooming)

But react-leaflet in v3 doesn't have onZoomChange event for MapContainer. So i can't get zoom updates for scaling my DivIcon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

found the solution with useMapEvents hook provided in react-leaflet v3:
https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map#usemapevents

```
import {useMapEvents} from "react-leaflet";
import {useState} from "react";

function MyComponent() {
    const [zoomLevel, setZoomLevel] = useState(5); // initial zoom level provided for MapContainer
    
    const mapEvents = useMapEvents({
        zoomend: () => {
            setZoomLevel(mapEvents.getZoom());
        },
    });

    console.log(zoomLevel);

    return null
}

function MyMapComponent() {
    return (
        <MapContainer center={[50.5, 30.5]} zoom={5}>
            <MyComponent />
        </MapContainer>
    )
}
```